Handling User Registration Without Email and Multiple Authentication Methods
I'm working on a web application where users can register using different authentication methods like Google and Facebook, but some users may have registered without providing an email address. Here's the challenging scenario I'm facing:
Existing Users Without Email:
Some users have registered using Facebook without providing an email address.( registered using mobile on fb)
Login with Google:
Now, these users try to log in using Google, where the email might not be provided or linked.
Handling Duplicate Accounts:
How do I handle scenarios where a user registered without an email tries to log in with another method (e.g., Google), but neither the provider ID nor the email matches an existing record?
Preventing Duplicate Accounts:
I want to ensure that no duplicate accounts are created while providing a smooth user experience.
Next Steps:
Should I prompt users to contact support for assistance?
How can I verify and link accounts securely without compromising user data?
Or should I get mobile number and validate ?
I tried as below flowchart, if there is issues be kind to solve that.
I'd appreciate any insights, best practices, or code examples on how to manage this scenario effectively. Thank you!

